# Is there a better way to write this function in Dart

Tags: algorithm, sorting, flutter, dart

I have a list of items ordered by date. What I want to do is essentially categorize these items by `today, yesterday, this week, this month, this year`

Right now I have this

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      Item itm = items[i];
      DateTime itmDate = itm.date;
      int diff = itmDate.diffNow();

      if (diff == 0) {
        today.add(itm);
        return;
      }

      if (diff == -1) {
        yesterday.add(itm);
        return;
      }

      if (diff <= -7) {
        week.add(itm);
        return;
      }

      if (diff <= -31) {
        month.add(itm);
        return;
      }


      if (diff <= -365) {
        year.add(itm);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
```

`diffNow()` is an extention of `DateTime` which just returns an `int` representing days since

How would I optimize this code?

Comment: Don't use `return` or you'll break out of the `for` loop - use `continue` instead.

Comment: As written, items that are, say, a year old would be classified in the `week` group.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Use  if(){} else if(){} else{}  and remove the return statements from all of them. Also if there are a lot of items in the array / list you want to get the length outside the for loop, as the for loop will calculate the condition for every iteration.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a switch instead,

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_switch_case_statement.htm

Check this out

Comment: That won't help with the `<=` cases.